# SVG features supported in iOS

Tags: ios, html, svg

I can't seem to find a good list of SVG features supported in iOS, the best I got is this:

http://caniuse.com/#cats=SVG

I'm studying the viability of developing a webpage that uses a lot of visual elements and we want to use SVG, I don't have deep knowledge of SVG, so I was wondering what are the major compatibility, performance and lack of features issues in iOS Safari.

From the link above it seems I can not use:
SMIL animations. Animations as SVG tags, correct? The link says:
"Partial support in Safari refers to not working in HTML files."
So it works as long as the SVG is not inside a HTML file? So it means that I can't use it at all?
Can I still animate using Javascript (with jQuery SVG for example)?

SVG Filters, now this I don't exactly know what this covers. Are gradients supported in SVG on iOS? What about other useful filters that are not supported (shadows)?

Comment: I think "not working in HTML files" is on contrast to XHTML files, rather than not working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much everything works other than filters. When it says not in HTML it's referring to the old HTML, as opposed To XHTML, served with the proper mimetype.

I'd Recommend either getting a cheap iPod touch (newest ones run ios 6), or a Mac with xcode and hence the simulator to test with, else this won't be much fun.

Comment: Agree, test on actual iOS has no parallel. Take advantage of the fact that the platform is not absurdly fragmented as Android

Answer (score 0):

For browser testing: http://browsershots.org/ to make magic happen, type your web page url to box wait - view screenshots and see how they are rendering or at all as svg? I know, its not the best possible way but its a start because it uses selected browsers to render your page :)

**Edit:**

Also, if seeing rendered images is not enough there is a tool http://spoon.net/browsers/ where you can use your page in correct browser **for free**